# What is the name of the POS1 key in xdotool?

Tags: xdotool

I need xdotool to press <kbd>pos1</kbd>, but I don't know the name of this key. It's not pos1, POS1, Pos1, Beginning. How can I find the name of the key which is used by xdotool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute

```
$ xev -event keyboard
```

and then just type the key you want to use.

Example output:

```
Outer window is 0x4a00001, inner window is 0x4a00002

KeymapNotify event, serial 24, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967230 0   0   0   16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x1a1, subw 0x0, time 109192145, (501,285), root:(503,393),
    state 0x0, keycode 36 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES,
"   XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d) "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x1a1, subw 0x0, time 109193882, (501,285), root:(503,393),
    state 0x0, keycode 110 (keysym 0xff50, Home), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x1a1, subw 0x0, time 109193953, (501,285), root:(503,393),
    state 0x0, keycode 110 (keysym 0xff50, Home), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
^C
```

The interesting part is `keycode 110 (keysym 0xff50, Home)`. So the name is `Home`.